# How to use MSBuild to compile for WinRT?

Tags: msbuild

I have a class library assembly that I have created in Visual Studio 2012.  I am wondering what parameters I should use to make sure the class library works under ARM, x86, and x64 for WinRT.  I currently have the project properties defined as AnyCPU.

Is all I need to do is define the NETFX_CORE constant?  Is there somewhere I specify for WinRT or the CPU?

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe MyClassLibrary.csproj
/t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=DEBUG /p:DefineConstants="NETFX_CORE"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same for WinRT, as for a desktop applications -- parameter is `/p:Platform=<name>`. E.g.:

```
msbuild MyClassLibrary.csproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=ARM
```